# how can i set dynamic testName @Test(testName="testing") in testng

Tags: java, testng

test cases designed using testng

`@Test(testName=" testname1")
public void starting(){
    System.out.println("Start the testing");
}`

i want to parameterized the testName 
can any one help on this

Comment: What is the purpose? What you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Use this annotation:
@Test(description="testname1")

Solution:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test(description="testname1")
public class TestNGDescriptionProperty {
    public void StartTheTesting() {
        System.out.println("Start the testing");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Test annotation level we need a dynamic value not a constant value.Is there any way to pass as parameter instead of constant value ?

Comment: Check this link: https://www.swtestacademy.com/change-test-name-testng-dataprovider/